# fancyref's \fref produces a line which is to long

Tags: line-breaking, koma-script, fancyref

I have the problem, that the line, where I have a `\fref`, is longer than the lines in the rest of the document.

I am using KOMA Script with `latexmk` and `xelatex`, to generate the document.

I have created a document with the same problem.

```
\documentclass[paper=A4,openany]{scrbook}
\RequirePackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[german,vario]{fancyref}

\KOMAoptions{
    draft=true,                 %TODO: set this variable to false, if final.
    BCOR=0mm,                   %bind-correct factor
    DIV=15                     %see scrguide: 
                                %   DIV=15: Border-up=19,80mm
                                %       Boder-inside=14,00mm
                                %       Print-Space=168,00mm x 237,60mm
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{blaaa}
\section{bbbb}
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah bluh bluh bluh bläh
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah bluh bluh bluh bläh
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah bluh bluh bluh bläh
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah bluh bluh bluh bläh

Basdfsassf giit si see Mniiinasdfs, im LXL-Binfsg aaa \textit{blaaaaaaaaa} blaaaaaaaaa. (siehe \fref{sec:subtest}

blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah bluh bluh bluh bläh (siehe \fref{sec:subtest}
\appendix
\chapter{aaa}
\section{test}
\subsection{subtest}\label{sec:subtest}
\end{document}
```

You can also see the problem in the following screenshot:
[image]

As far as I know this problem occurs not very often, but how can I tell `latex` to put the reference number to the next line and leave the "Abschnitt" in the current line?

I don't want to enter a manual `\linebreak` before the `\fref`.

Comment: I suggest to use `cleveref` rather -- it supports line-breaking (fancyref is from 1999, so little bit 'aged')

Comment: Welcome! @ChristianHupfer I prefer `fancyref`, personally. It suits my workflow better than `cleveref`. Just because something is from 1999 does not mean that it is therefore automatically inferior to more recent packages. There's nothing wrong with `cleveref` but it is not, in my opinion, a satisfactory replacement for `fancyref`. No reason it should be - it is not designed as a replacement.

Comment: not much you can do except the same strategies you can always follow when you have an overfull hbox

Comment: @clemens Not really. This is due to a specific design decision on the part of `fancyref`'s author, as far as I can tell. If you want to make a different decision, you can override that. So although you are right in a way, the implementation of one such strategy is package-specific. At least, if I've not misunderstood too badly.

Comment: @cfr alright you *can* have “Abschnitt” and the number on seperate lines but that is not a very satisfactory solution. It is one of the places where when typing you would naturally use `Abschnitt~\ref{sec:foo}` when using classical cross-referencing (i.e. *prevent* a line break)

Comment: @clemens I agree and I don't do this. But that is exactly what the OP wanted to happen and, given that aim, the solution needs to adjust what `fancyref` is doing. So the answer to *this question* has to be package-specific, even if a different solution might be typographically preferable.

Comment: @clemens But you are probably right that my answer should make this caveat a bit more explicit.

Comment: @cfr as long as we agree that this is the last resort when all other options (`microtype` and what not) have failed :)

Comment: @clemens As I now say explicitly in my answer, I use `fancyref` for everything and I have never altered this default. I had to look up the code to get the right command to redefine. Since the OP is using XeTeX, `microtype` may be less useful than it often is. But it is certainly a good idea, even when its functions are limited by the choice of (or need for a particular) engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `fancyref` keeps the name of the section with the reference i.e. with `\thesection`. This is not a bad idea, frankly. I use `fancyref` in all my documents and I have never changed this particular default. (I've added to the reference thingies it knows about, and I've change prefixes and names etc., but I've not allowed line breaks where they would not otherwise be permitted.)

If you wish to allow a line break here, you can simply redefine the spacing to use a breaking space:

```
\documentclass[paper=A4,openany,ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[german,vario]{fancyref}
\renewcommand*{\fancyrefloosespacing}{\ }
\KOMAoptions{
    draft=true,
    BCOR=0mm,
    DIV=15}

\begin{document}
\chapter{blaaa}
\section{bbbb}
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah bluh bluh bluh bläh blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah bluh bluh bluh bläh blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah bluh bluh bluh bläh blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah bluh bluh bluh bläh

Basdfsassf giit si see Mniiinasdfs, im LXL-Binfsg aaa \textit{blaaaaaaaaa} blaaaaaaaaa. (siehe \fref{sec:subtest}


blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah bluh bluh bluh bläh (siehe \fref{sec:subtest}
\appendix
\chapter{aaa}
\section{test}
\subsection{subtest}\label{sec:subtest}
\end{document}
```

In this case, TeX also prefers a break before the reference in the second case:

[image: adjusted spacing]

Comment: Wow, this works as expected, thank you so much! (If I could vote you up, I would do it!)

Comment: @byteunit You're welcome. Do note the discussion in comments: this should be a last resort, really. Also, KOMA is complaining a good deal about your page layout ;). See the warnings on your console.

Comment: @cfr I've been playing around with making a ltx3 based version of `fancyref` just to learn more about ltx3. This seems to be something to put on the TODO list for that. (it is not a package that is going to show up any time soon). I've also been using `fancyref` for a long time, but have a lot of local additions to it to make it easier to use.

Comment: @daleif That sounds interesting. Though it isn't clear how wise this particular modification would be ;).

Comment: @cfr, but it would be easy to add as an option to `\Fref` for this particular single `\Fref` instead of having to do so globally. I'll let to know when I have something more publicly useful.